# How to show page via resource controller laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Home.blade.php is starting when I route it directly but not when I call it from resource controller !!

```
Route::resource('list','listcontroller');
```

And I call it in index method :

```
  class listcontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return View('list.Home');
    }
```

Comment: View('list.Home') is it work from route file??

Comment: if I route this , is working :
Route::get('/Home', function()
{
    return View('Home');
});

Comment: It works for 'Home', but doesn't work for 'list.Home'? Then use 'Home' in the controller :D

Comment: Use capital in your class names, for christ sake... programming 101 here, man.

Answer (score 1):

Change your index function to the following-

```
public function index()
{
  return View('Home');
}
```

And you will get the corresponding view at `base_url/list`

or if you want to get with `/list/home` url then change your route to-

```
Route::resource('list/home','listcontroller');
```

If you want to set a `base_url` othen you can use [route prefix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-prefixes)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'list'], function () {
     Route::resource('home','listcontroller');
});
```

Comment: then try Route::resource('list/home','listcontroller');

Comment: thanks for your time , but I need list as a root 'folder'.
url/list/home
url/list/about etc

Comment: then look for route prefix, have a look at this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-prefixes

Answer (score 0):

1)Your controller name is not standard write listController.

2)make sure about your route names:

> php artisan route:list

3)in blade write

`<a href="{{route('list.index')}}"></a>`

and try it

Answer (score 0):

Any view should be addressed by their path from view folder separated by . (Dot) and with correct character case.

For example if you have `home.blade.php` in view folder you should call it by `view(“home”)`.

Beside that you can address to any routes by “route” helper function and passing route name to it.

As @amini.swallow said you can reach to your route list by running php `artisan route:list` command.

In your case you can create link like this :

`<a href=“{{route(“list.index”)}}”>click here</a>`

Hope it helps.